# How can you use xpath-functions with XSLT 2.0?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

In order to use [xpath-functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#namespace-prefixes) (specifically the `fn` part), I included the respective namespace into my xslt stylesheet, like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="2.0"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
>
```

As [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#namespace-prefixes) by W3C.

However, when I use `fn:document-uri`, my XSLT engines tell me I called an unknown function/extension:

```
  <xsl:variable name="uri" select="fn:document-uri()" />
```

Opera says:

> This document had an invalid XSLT stylesheet. Error message from the XSLT engine:
>   Error: XPath expression compilation failed: fn:document-uri()
>   Details: compilation error (characters 1-17, "fn:document-uri()"): unknown function called: '{ http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions, document-uri }'

Firefox says:

> Error during XSLT transformation: An unknown XPath extension function was called.

And `xsltproc` refuses transformation, because of xslt 2.0.

So, how do I specify the `fn` namespace properly?

Comment: Bitmask, did my answer provide the information you were after, or do you still have question on this?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: Technically you have, but a workaround would be great (although I don't think it's possible). That's why I left the question open a bit longer.

Comment: I did clearly say that a *compliant* XSLT 1.0 processor *must not* implement XPath 2.0 functions. This very clearly means that there is no "workaround" -- if one needs XPath 2.0 in XSLT, then they *must* use an XSLT 2.0 (or upper version) processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem is that you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor and an XSLT 1.0 processor doesn't know (and must not know) anything about XPath 2.0 functions**.

If you use a real XSLT 2.0 processor, you don't even have to specify the function namespace -- it is a default namespace for any unprefixed function name.

**For example, this XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select="document-uri(.)" />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:sequence select="document-uri(document(''))" />
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when executed with Saxon 9.1.5 under the XSelerator, produces correctly the URLs of the source XML document and the stylesheet itself**:

```
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xml
file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/bin/marrowtr.xsl
```